# Problem to type few letters in Kannada

Tags: input-method

I am using ubuntu 14.04, I can type in Kannada except few letters. It is unable to type these letters: ಅ ಆ ಇ ಈ ಉ ಊ ಋ ೠ ಎ ಏ ಐ ಒ ಓ ಔ. I can't type all ovals. Ibus installed and in system settings-language support-language Kannada is installed. And in text entry settings Kannada (KaGaPa Phonetics) added. Even I add Kannada also the same problem is coming. If I type a for ಅ the display will come as ' ಾ'. All other letters can type.

Comment: Can you post the English transliteration of these characters (what they sound like)? Some longer vowels, aspirated consonants have to typed using Shift key, I think.

Comment: ಅ a, ಆ-ā, ಇ-i, ಈ-ī, ಉ-ou, ಊ-oū, ಋ-ru, ೠ-rū, ಎ-ye, ಏ-yē, ಐ-ai, ಒ-o, ಓ-ō, ಔ-au

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kannada_alphabet

Answer (score 1):

https://www.libreoffice.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=67993

ALTGR key should be used with vowel key (a i u e y o v r) to get "ಅ ಇ ಉ ಎ ಐ ಒ ಔ ಋ"

shift key + a to get ಆ

ALTGR + shift key should be used with vowel key (i u e o r) to get "ಈ ಊ ಏ ಓ"

Answer (score 0):

- Install Synaptic Package Manager
- Uninstall scim
- Install ibus
- On Top Right Part of the Screen, Next to Date, Click on En.
- Choose Text Entry Settings.
- Click on + Icon,
- Add Kannada itrans m17n (IBus)

No need to even restart/logout.

ಕನ್ನಡ ಕನ್ನಡ, ಹಾ ಸವಿಗನ್ನಡ

Answer (score 0):

**Installation part**

1. go to "Language and support" in Ubuntu/Xubuntu,
   let it install pending packages and
   search search for Kannada and check it.
2. check the Keyboard input method and if it's none,
   change it to to iBus (in Ubuntu) and i see XIM (in Xubuntu).
3. close the "Language and Support"
4. after logout and re-login, got the iBus option.
5. Open terminal, and run: sudo apt-get install ibus-m17n m17n-contrib
   the ibus-m17n was already installed, but m17n-contrib not found.
   also the dependent libm17n-0 is already installed.
6. Like "text entry" of Ubuntu, search for "keyboard" of Xubuntu and add keyboard layout:
   Indian > Kannada (KaGaPa, phonetic)
7. right click on top right corner (the date/time or wifi or battery panel)
   Panel > Add new Item > Search for "Keyboard Layouts", select > Add
8. Change Keyboard Layout on click (toggle state).
9. Set a keyboard short cut to toggle "keyboard layout",
   Right click on language toggle icon in pannel > keyboard settings > Layout (tab) > Change layout option > (select) Win+Space
10. After adding keyboard short cut for switching language, same can be used at login prompt.
    Just in case the screen locked while, language is not English, then it can switched back to English using same short cut.

**Typing Kannada on Ubuntu/Xubuntu:**

With KaGaPa phonetic typing selected, you can type Kannada letters using follow:

| ಕ | ಕಾ | ಕಿ | ಕೀ | ಕು | ಕೂ | ಕೃ | ಕೆ | ಕೇ | ಕೈ | ಕೊ | ಕೋ | ಕೌ | ಕಂ | ಕಃ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| k | ka | ki | kI | ku | kU | kR | ke | kE | kY | ko | kO | kV | kM | kH |

| ಅ | ಆ | ಇ | ಈ | ಉ | ಊ | ಋ | ಎ | ಏ | ಐ | ಒ | ಓ | ಔ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AltGr+a | A | AltGr+i | AltGr+I | AltGr+u | AltGr+U | AltGr+r | AltGr+e | AltGr+E | AltGr+y | AltGr+o | AltGr+O | AltGr+v |

| ಂ | ಃ | ್ | ಕ್ | ಕನ್ನಡ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| M | H | f | kf | knfnw |

Use f for Emphasis as shown above (ಒತ್ತಕ್ಷರಗಳಿಗೆ, ವ್ಯಂಜನಗಳ ನಡುವೆ f ಉಪಯೊಗಿಸಿ).

| ಕ | ಖ | ಗ | ಘ | ಞ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| k | K | g | G | z |

| ಚ | ಛ | ಜ | ಝ | ಙ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| c | C | j | J | Z |

| ಟ | ಠ | ಡ | ಢ | ಣ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| q | Q | w | W | N |

| ತ | ಥ | ದ | ಧ | ನ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| t | T | d | D | n |

| ಪ | ಫ | ಬ | ಭ | ಮ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| p | P | b | B | m |

| ಯ | ರ | ಲ | ವ | ಶ | ಷ | ಸ | ಹ | ಳ | ೞ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| y | r | l | v | S | x | s | h | L | AltGr+x |

For complete list of short-cut check the file `/usr/share/m17n/kn-inscript.mim` of your system.